# custom css styling for jquery mobile button

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I have [this button](http://users8.jabry.com/captdragon/ol/jqButtonIcon.html) which i have added a custom icon to.

I would like to remove the lighter gray which is within the icon. 
[image]

This lighter gray is not part of the icon, it's got to be somewhere within jquery's CSS which i should be able to overide. 
[image]

What can I do to my CSS to accomplish this?

You can view source on the link i've provided but here is the current CSS:

```
.ui-icon-my-map {
    background-image: url("images/103-map.png");
    background-position: 4px 50%;
    background-size: 26px 21px;
    height: 24px;
    margin-top: -12px !important;
    width: 35px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your problem is:

```
.ui-icon, .ui-icon-searchfield::after {
  background: #666;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
}
```

just add

```
.ui-icon-my-map {
[...]
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can overide with your css (put it after jquery mobile css load, or add important at the end).

```
.ui-icon, .ui-icon-searchfield::after {
background: none;
}
```

Comment: This removed my icon. hannes and thepriebe got it. (+1) for the effort.

Comment: It depends of where you do it. It works only if you change directly the css.

Answer (score 1):

For the style of this guy

```
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-my-map ui-icon-shadow"></span>
```

Add:

```
background-color: transparent;
```

Comment: (+1) for the effort but Hannes answered first.

Answer (score 1):

Set the background color of the span to transparent.

```
.ui-icon-my-map{
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css and go to line and find `.ui-icon, .ui-icon-searchfield:after`

Then on background change to

```
url("images/icons-18-white.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
```

instead of

```
url("images/icons-18-white.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this work:

- http://jsfiddle.net/tR9Cj/

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <a id="bnt_edge" data-role="button" data-inline="false" data-transition="turn" href="#" rel="external" data-icon="my-map" data-theme="c" data-iconshadow="false">My Button</a>
</div>​
```

CSS

```
.ui-icon-my-map {
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjB5L.png");
    background-position: 4px 50%;
    background-size: 26px 21px;
    height: 24px;
    margin-top: -12px !important;
    width: 35px;
    background-color: transparent;
}​
```